# StackService cache update on database data change

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) to build my API/Service. Database communication is done through OrmLite which is supported by [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/). Database connection is being used through IDbConnectionFactory.

My database (SQL Server) is being updated through SQL Replication (receiving data updates from another database). I want my cache (service level) to be cleared once a update is made to the database through any source.

Is there any way i could use SQLDependency or any other mechanism to always get the updated data along with using cache?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would use something like ServiceBroker to get notifications for database changes.

Try checking out this other question, someone provides an answer with SQLDependency: [How to monitor SQL Server table changes by using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288434/how-to-monitor-sql-server-table-changes-by-using-c)

I'm new to ServiceStack myself so I'm unsure if they have within their framework something that would do this with minimal setup.