# What happens (or doesn't happen) in a chrome tab opened in the background?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, polymer, google-chrome-devtools

**Observation:** I am running an SPA in Polymer and when I open internal links in new background tabs in chrome, the pages don't finish loading (ajax and all) until I focus on the tab.

**Questions:** What is chrome waiting for user focus to do -or- What is Polymer waiting for before it finishes rendering the page and sending ajax requests?

**Bonus:** How can I open a dev tools panel targeting a tab I have opened in the background to observe what is/isn't happening?

**Bonus Answer:** If you open dev tools on a tab, navigate away from the tab, then refresh the dev tools, the associated tab will also refresh and simulate having been opened in the backgroun.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22070842/361762) all processing is stopped in background tabs. [A different answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12522580/361762) suggests using WebWorkers to keep a thread running in the background.

Comment: Except that if you go to http://builtwithpolymer.org/ and open any of the sites in new background tabs. They all seem to complete loading before in the background before I focus them.

Comment: Relevant: [Wikipedia - If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest)

Comment: @zerkms I just expect to see it laying down in the dirt when i finally am around, not suspended in the air waiting for me to see it fall.

Answer (score 5):

In Polymer, `core-ajax` with the `auto` attribute set to `true` uses Polymer `job` utility ([source](https://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax/blob/master/core-ajax.html#L348)). Polymer's job utility uses the `requestAnimationFrame()` function ([source](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/0.5.x/src/lib/job.js)). According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033979/863924) and [here](http://www.john-smith.me/disparity-in-requestanimationframe-behaviour-between-chrome-and), chrome pauses on this function completely when the tab is inactive.

**Solution:** By removing the auto attribute from my `core-ajax` elements and manually calling the `go()` method on the ready event, I was able to get my pages to fully load in the background.

Comment: Any idea how this works in Polymer 1.0 with `iron-ajax`?