# Can a web application perform tasks when Chrome is minimized on Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-applications

I am developing a web application that works as a timer+logger. It tracks how much time has passed between the user starting the timer and stopping it (just an example).

My question is - if the user starts the timer and opens another app/moved chrome to the backgrounds - does the timer still log time?

By default the time would be logged on client-side, but if that wouldn't work - maybe moving logging to server-side would help it?

Finally, if nothing previously mentioned works, is this functionality achievable using Cordova?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Chrome unloads tabs that you're not using - according to [an answer last year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22061280/3934789) music can play in the background but arbitrary javascript doesn't.

Native and Cordova Android apps can get around the tab restriction by using a [background service](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki).