# HTML5 audio/javascript stops working on android(google chrome) when screen is turned off

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio

I have created a Web App which plays music playlist and it works well on desktop browsers and also in mozilla and opera of android. But When I play the songs on Chrome browser of Android and I turn off the screen, it stops after playing the current song. And as soon as I turn the screen on, it starts loading the next song in line.

From my observations, what I have understood is Google Chrome browser on android pauses the javascript code from executing if the screen is turned off till the screen is not waken up again. Is there any way I can prevent my specific library from pausing? Any approach or events?

Some related this question is what I am looking for: [JavaScript halts in inactive android Chrome tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061280/javascript-halts-in-inactive-android-chrome-tab)

There are so many WebApps which does not stop playing music. Does it need some permissions from Google App Store?

Comment: You could try forcing touch events while the audio is playing so the browser doesn't disable the browser window while the screen is off. This is not recommended however as it would eat up memory and battery.

Comment: you might be able to bypass the behavior from cordova, but not "just a page". i have to keep my phones from sleeping using an option in developer settings about keeping on when plugged in, in order to get them to be decent audio-playing slaves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can change the behaviour of the Chrome app, if they want to save battery in the background and stop the javascript, you won't reactivate it.

There are maybe some other ways to get it working.

1. Tell your users that they should use Firefox or Opera on their mobile device.
2. All apps are allowed to play or stream music in the background, so you could make or use an app for your task.
3. Maybe you can use the default music player app on android. Open a playlist of streams using the app. (I don't know if this is possible, because I have no android device.)

I know that is not exactly what you want, but a maybe a way to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

check what happens with youtube, at least few years ago i had an awful time dealing with that and that's what proved to my client it cant be done in the given time frame and budget. that was actually device specific, on some devices it worked fine and on others it didnt. check if it happens on other devices. the only solutions i could think of ware either to prevent screen turn off (on problematic devices or all of them at the beginning), or to build an app and handle onPause event