# C# - Automatically Re-Bind .Net ListView if more data is available

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I am creating an application and some of the information relies on data found in an SQL table. On pageload, this is bound to a ListView, but how do I get the list to auto refresh (re-bind) if more data is added to the SQL table?

I have considered calling the bind every 10 seconds or so, but that seems to be a bit old fashioned.

Any tips?

Comment: Look into the [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class. [SO Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5288505/1895201)

Comment: Possibly early days but it seems that SqlDependacy is what I need for this. I will try it out later and update with my progress. Thanks! :D

Answer (score -1):

What you have is called Pulling Data from server.
What you want is called pushing data to Client.
Try [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) for pushing data.