# How can I get recently updated data from db without user interaction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is my problematic situation.

My SQL Server database has a table called reservation and contain data about

ReservationId,
DriverId,
ReservationType,

when a customer done reservation ,It added a row with reservationid, DriverId , ReservationType="Y" to the db.

I am able to take this data from db with pressing button.

but I need to get that reservation data continuously(if there have a new record) from db and shown that in real time in a list .

Is that possible using Asp.net MVC and Linq or can someone suggest a way to do that possible .

Comment: Is a `date` or `dateTime` included with the data? This would allow to search for most recent data

Comment: We used something similar to the first answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288434/how-to-monitor-sql-server-table-changes-by-using-c

Comment: @Symon I can take data recently from db  when the page loading but  after that if i added new reservation data it is only recognize when again page loading .I need track data in real-time For an example lets say after page loading someone add reservation .I need to get that one without user interaction .this is possible in java-script each and every time checking db but i don't know how to do that in C# and Asp.net mvc .thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Do you really need asp.net mvc 4? As it is quite easy to do this in asp.net core, but quite complicated in that old framework.

Comment: You wrote: "My SQL Server". Do you mean a "MySQL server" instance or _your_ Microsoft SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 1):

That can be achieved by using SqlDependency class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency