# Event on deferred IQueryable execution

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I don't know even this is a reasonable question or not, but I am wondering, is there any way to register an event on `IQueryable` execution so when the `IQueryable` runs the event gets triggered.

Problem is I am passing the `IQueryable` to a table object and I have no idea when the data being populated into the table but I want to do some action after my `IQueryable` got populated or executed.

For instance something like this:

```
IQueryable list = context.data.Where(....);
list.onExecutionCompleted += DoSomeAction;
```

Comment: Is your process that is inserting the data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor SQL Server table changes by using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288434/how-to-monitor-sql-server-table-changes-by-using-c)

Comment: No, I have Entity framework Interceptor, I want to unregister it when the query is done.